# How can I have EF5 create a database and not tables with EF code first?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework 5 with SQL Server 2012. I am using code first and I have the following code:

```
    new DataInitializer();

    public DataInitializer()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ABCContext>(null);
        CreateMembership();
        CreateUserData();

    }

    private void CreateMembership()
    {
        try {
            using (var context = new ABCContext()) {

                if (!context.Database.Exists()) {
                    ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
```

At this point the database **and all the tables** are getting created. I would like to have the
database created but not all the tables. These I want to create manually. Is there a way 
that I can EF create the database but not the tables?

Comment: You can do it as convert all DbContext field to comment, then debug your poject. Perhaps then will created only database)).

Comment: Do you want this for development or should it be part of a deployed application?